# Hall effect sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I've taken velocity readings of a wheel using a hall effect sensor. Is it possible to take the **acceleration** readings corresponding to those velocities as well? Do I just have to divide the velocity by the time taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can divide speed by time and get acceleration, obviously that will give you the mean acceleration between speed reading.

Comment: Cheers Lesto!!!